# Which format string to use with printf() for a time as 789:01.234

Tags: c, time, formatting, printf

From a double I want to print a time in minutes and seconds including their fractional part up to 6 digits without trailing zeros.

As by the nature of formats it should be possible to nest the solution within further parameters in a single `printf()` statement!

The time variable I want to print is a double in second unit and does not exceed the range of some tens of hours.

```
    double time1 = 123.456789; //   2:03.456789 some text
    double time2 = 12345.6;    // 205:45.6 some text
    printf("format: %-16s time1: %.6g some text\n", "%.6g", time1);
    printf("format: %-16s time2: %.6g some text\n", "%.6g", time2);
    printf("format: %-16s time1: %3d:%09.6f some text\n", "%3d:%09.6f", (int)time1 / 60, fmod(time1, 60));
    printf("format: %-16s time2: %3d:%09.6f some text\n", "%3d:%09.6f", (int)time2 / 60, fmod(time2, 60));
    printf("format: %-16s time1: %3d:%09.6g some text\n", "%3d:%09.6g", (int)time1 / 60, fmod(time1, 60));
    printf("format: %-16s time2: %3d:%09.6g some text\n", "%3d:%09.6g", (int)time2 / 60, fmod(time2, 60));
    printf("format: %-16s time1: %3d:%0.6g some text\n", "%3d:%0.6g", (int)time1 / 60, fmod(time1, 60));
    printf("format: %-16s time2: %3d:%0.6g some text\n", "%3d:%0.6g", (int)time2 / 60, fmod(time2, 60));
    printf("format: %-16s time1: %3d:%02d%.6f some text\n", "%3d:%02d%.6f", (int)time1 / 60, (int)time1 % 60, fmod(time1, 1));
    printf("format: %-16s time2: %3d:%02d%.6f some text\n", "%3d:%02d%.6f", (int)time2 / 60, (int)time2 % 60, fmod(time2, 1));
    printf("format: %-16s time1: %3d:%02d%.6g some text\n", "%3d:%02d%.6g", (int)time1 / 60, (int)time1 % 60, fmod(time1, 1));
    printf("format: %-16s time2: %3d:%02d%.6g some text\n", "%3d:%02d%.6g", (int)time2 / 60, (int)time2 % 60, fmod(time2, 1));
    printf("format: %-16s time1: %3d:%02d%0.6g some text\n", "%3d:%02d%0.6g", (int)time1 / 60, (int)time1 % 60, fmod(time1, 1));
    printf("format: %-16s time2: %3d:%02d%0.6g some text\n", "%3d:%02d%0.6g", (int)time2 / 60, (int)time2 % 60, fmod(time2, 1));
```

Expected:

```
time1:   2:03.456789 some text
time2: 205:45.6 some text
```

Result:

```
format: %.6g             time1: 123.457 some text
format: %.6g             time2: 12345.6 some text
format: %3d:%09.6f       time1:   2:03.456789 some text   <- OK
format: %3d:%09.6f       time2: 205:45.600000 some text   <- trailing zeros
format: %3d:%09.6g       time1:   2:003.45679 some text   <- 3 digits for minutes, missing 8
format: %3d:%09.6g       time2: 205:0000045.6 some text   <- 7 digits for minutes
format: %3d:%0.6g        time1:   2:3.45679 some text     <- 1 digit for minutes, missing 8
format: %3d:%0.6g        time2: 205:45.6 some text        <- OK
format: %3d:%02d%.6f     time1:   2:030.456789 some text  <- leading 0
format: %3d:%02d%.6f     time2: 205:450.600000 some text  <- leading 0, trailing zeros
format: %3d:%02d%.6g     time1:   2:030.456789 some text  <- leading 0
format: %3d:%02d%.6g     time2: 205:450.6 some text       <- leading 0
format: %3d:%02d%0.6g    time1:   2:030.456789 some text  <- leading 0
format: %3d:%02d%0.6g    time2: 205:450.6 some text       <- leading 0
```

An additional format would be nice:

```
time2: 3:25:45.6 some text
```

Comment: How about `%0.6g`?

Comment: @ScottHunter Sorry, does not work, see edit above.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This approach uses the stack instead of heap memory, so it should be faster.

The goal is fast code, small footprint and VERY BIG values don't matter.
Only in very rare rounding corner cases some more CPU cycles are needed.

It also allows the combination with other formats and values in further `printf()`.

NEW: An additional solution for format: `h:mm:ss.nnnnnn`

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <math.h>

#define MAX_BUF_SZ 32
#ifndef DBL_MAX
#define DBL_MAX  1.7976931348623157e+308
#endif

static char *minutes_str(char *buf, double time) {
    const char *format = (time >= 0 ? "%d:%09.6f" : "-%d:%09.6f");
    time = (fabs(time) > INT_MAX * 60.0 ? INT_MAX * 60.0 : fabs(time));
    int len = snprintf(buf, MAX_BUF_SZ, format, (int)(time / 60), fmod(time, 60));
    if (len - 9 >= 0 && buf[len - 9] > '5') // correct rare rounding issue
        len = snprintf(buf, MAX_BUF_SZ, format, (int)(time / 60) + 1, .0);
    while (buf[--len] == '0'); // search trailing zeros or ...
    buf[len + (buf[len] != '.')] = '\0'; // dot and strip them
    return buf;
}

/**
 * Convenience macro. The return value should be used only directly in
 * function arguments but never stand-alone.
 */
#define time2minutestr(time) minutes_str((char[MAX_BUF_SZ]){'\0'}, time)

static char *hours_string(char *buf, double time)
{
    const char *format = (time >= 0 ? "%d:%02d:%09.6f" : "-%d:%02d:%09.6f");
    if (time == (double)NAN)
        printf("Invalid number\n");
    time = (fabs(time) > INT_MAX * 60.0 * 60.0 ? INT_MAX * 60.0 * 60.0 : fabs(time));
    int hours = time / 60 / 60, minutes = fmod(time / 60, 60);
    int len = snprintf(buf, MAX_BUF_SZ, format, hours, minutes, fmod(time, 60));
    if (len - 9 >= 0 && buf[len - 9] > '5') { // correct rare rounding issue
        if (++minutes > 59) {
            minutes = 0;
            hours++;
        }
        len = snprintf(buf, MAX_BUF_SZ, format, hours, minutes, .0);
    }
    while (buf[--len] == '0'); // search trailing zeros or ...
    buf[len + (buf[len] != '.')] = '\0'; // dot and strip them
    return buf;
}

/**
 * Convenience macro. The return value should be used only directly in
 * function arguments but never stand-alone.
 */
#define time2hourstr(time) hours_string((char[MAX_BUF_SZ]){'\0'}, time)

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    double a[] = {
        0, -1, 1, 59, 60, 61,
        121.1, 121.11, 121.111, 121.1111, 121.11111, 121.111111,
        12345.6,
        123.456789,
        129.9999994,
        129.9999995,
        599.9999994,
        599.9999995,
        599.99999951,
        599.9999999,
        23.9999999999,
        999.0000005, 1000.0000005, -999.0000005, -1000.0000005,
        999.9999999, -999.9999999,
        1e6, 1e12, 1e18,
        4321.0, -0.0, 59.9999994, 59.9999996,
        INT_MAX * 60.0, INT_MAX * 60.0 + 1234,
        -(INT_MAX + 1.0) * 60.0, -(INT_MAX + 1.0) * 60.0 - 1234,
        (double)ULLONG_MAX * 64.0, DBL_MAX, 1.0 / 0.0, (double)NAN,
    };
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]); i++) {
        printf("%32.16g", a[i]);
        printf(" --> %s %s\n", time2minutestr(a[i]), "some text");
        printf("%32.16g", -a[i]);
        printf(" --> %s %s\n", time2minutestr(-a[i]), "some text");
    }
    printf("                                H A P P Y !\n");

    double b[] = {
        0, -1, 1, 59, 60, 61,
        12345.6,
        123.456789,
        3609.9999995,
        3609.99999951,
        359999.9999994,
        359999.9999995,
        359999.99999951,
        719999.9999995, 7199.9999999999,
        1e6, 1e12, 1e18,
        INT_MAX * 60.0, INT_MAX * 60.0 * 60.0,
        -(INT_MAX + 1.0) * 60.0, -(INT_MAX + 1.0) * 60.0 * 60.0,
        (double)ULLONG_MAX * 64.0, DBL_MAX, 1.0 / 0.0, (double)NAN,
    };
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(b) / sizeof(b[0]); i++) {
        printf("%32.16g", b[i]);
        printf(" --> %s %s\n", time2hourstr(b[i]), "some other text");
        printf("%32.16g", -b[i]);
        printf(" --> %s %s\n", time2hourstr(-b[i]), "some other text");
    }
    printf("                            V E R Y   H A P P Y !\n");

    return (0);
}
```

Output:

```
                               0 --> 0:00 some text
                              -0 --> 0:00 some text
                              -1 --> -0:01 some text
                               1 --> 0:01 some text
                               1 --> 0:01 some text
                              -1 --> -0:01 some text
                              59 --> 0:59 some text
                             -59 --> -0:59 some text
                              60 --> 1:00 some text
                             -60 --> -1:00 some text
                              61 --> 1:01 some text
                             -61 --> -1:01 some text
                           121.1 --> 2:01.1 some text
                          -121.1 --> -2:01.1 some text
                          121.11 --> 2:01.11 some text
                         -121.11 --> -2:01.11 some text
                         121.111 --> 2:01.111 some text
                        -121.111 --> -2:01.111 some text
                        121.1111 --> 2:01.1111 some text
                       -121.1111 --> -2:01.1111 some text
                       121.11111 --> 2:01.11111 some text
                      -121.11111 --> -2:01.11111 some text
                      121.111111 --> 2:01.111111 some text
                     -121.111111 --> -2:01.111111 some text
                         12345.6 --> 205:45.6 some text
                        -12345.6 --> -205:45.6 some text
                      123.456789 --> 2:03.456789 some text
                     -123.456789 --> -2:03.456789 some text
                     129.9999994 --> 2:09.999999 some text
                    -129.9999994 --> -2:09.999999 some text
                     129.9999995 --> 2:10 some text
                    -129.9999995 --> -2:10 some text
                     599.9999994 --> 9:59.999999 some text
                    -599.9999994 --> -9:59.999999 some text
               599.9999994999999 --> 9:59.999999 some text
              -599.9999994999999 --> -9:59.999999 some text
                    599.99999951 --> 10:00 some text
                   -599.99999951 --> -10:00 some text
                     599.9999999 --> 10:00 some text
                    -599.9999999 --> -10:00 some text
                   23.9999999999 --> 0:24 some text
                  -23.9999999999 --> -0:24 some text
               999.0000005000001 --> 16:39.000001 some text
              -999.0000005000001 --> -16:39.000001 some text
                    1000.0000005 --> 16:40.000001 some text
                   -1000.0000005 --> -16:40.000001 some text
              -999.0000005000001 --> -16:39.000001 some text
               999.0000005000001 --> 16:39.000001 some text
                   -1000.0000005 --> -16:40.000001 some text
                    1000.0000005 --> 16:40.000001 some text
                     999.9999999 --> 16:40 some text
                    -999.9999999 --> -16:40 some text
                    -999.9999999 --> -16:40 some text
                     999.9999999 --> 16:40 some text
                         1000000 --> 16666:40 some text
                        -1000000 --> -16666:40 some text
                   1000000000000 --> 2147483647:00 some text
                  -1000000000000 --> -2147483647:00 some text
                           1e+18 --> 2147483647:00 some text
                          -1e+18 --> -2147483647:00 some text
                            4321 --> 72:01 some text
                           -4321 --> -72:01 some text
                              -0 --> 0:00 some text
                               0 --> 0:00 some text
                      59.9999994 --> 0:59.999999 some text
                     -59.9999994 --> -0:59.999999 some text
                      59.9999996 --> 1:00 some text
                     -59.9999996 --> -1:00 some text
                    128849018820 --> 2147483647:00 some text
                   -128849018820 --> -2147483647:00 some text
                    128849020054 --> 2147483647:00 some text
                   -128849020054 --> -2147483647:00 some text
                   -128849018880 --> -2147483647:00 some text
                    128849018880 --> 2147483647:00 some text
                   -128849020114 --> -2147483647:00 some text
                    128849020114 --> 2147483647:00 some text
           1.180591620717411e+21 --> 2147483647:00 some text
          -1.180591620717411e+21 --> -2147483647:00 some text
          1.797693134862316e+308 --> 2147483647:00 some text
         -1.797693134862316e+308 --> -2147483647:00 some text
                             inf --> 2147483647:00 some text
                            -inf --> -2147483647:00 some text
                             nan --> --2147483648:      nan some text
                            -nan --> --2147483648:      nan some text
                                H A P P Y !
                               0 --> 0:00:00 some other text
                              -0 --> 0:00:00 some other text
                              -1 --> -0:00:01 some other text
                               1 --> 0:00:01 some other text
                               1 --> 0:00:01 some other text
                              -1 --> -0:00:01 some other text
                              59 --> 0:00:59 some other text
                             -59 --> -0:00:59 some other text
                              60 --> 0:01:00 some other text
                             -60 --> -0:01:00 some other text
                              61 --> 0:01:01 some other text
                             -61 --> -0:01:01 some other text
                         12345.6 --> 3:25:45.6 some other text
                        -12345.6 --> -3:25:45.6 some other text
                      123.456789 --> 0:02:03.456789 some other text
                     -123.456789 --> -0:02:03.456789 some other text
                    3609.9999995 --> 1:00:09.999999 some other text
                   -3609.9999995 --> -1:00:09.999999 some other text
                   3609.99999951 --> 1:00:10 some other text
                  -3609.99999951 --> -1:00:10 some other text
                  359999.9999994 --> 99:59:59.999999 some other text
                 -359999.9999994 --> -99:59:59.999999 some other text
                  359999.9999995 --> 99:59:59.999999 some other text
                 -359999.9999995 --> -99:59:59.999999 some other text
                 359999.99999951 --> 100:00:00 some other text
                -359999.99999951 --> -100:00:00 some other text
                  719999.9999995 --> 199:59:59.999999 some other text
                 -719999.9999995 --> -199:59:59.999999 some other text
                 7199.9999999999 --> 2:00:00 some other text
                -7199.9999999999 --> -2:00:00 some other text
                         1000000 --> 277:46:40 some other text
                        -1000000 --> -277:46:40 some other text
                   1000000000000 --> 277777777:46:40 some other text
                  -1000000000000 --> -277777777:46:40 some other text
                           1e+18 --> 2147483647:00:00 some other text
                          -1e+18 --> -2147483647:00:00 some other text
                    128849018820 --> 35791394:07:00 some other text
                   -128849018820 --> -35791394:07:00 some other text
                   7730941129200 --> 2147483647:00:00 some other text
                  -7730941129200 --> -2147483647:00:00 some other text
                   -128849018880 --> -35791394:08:00 some other text
                    128849018880 --> 35791394:08:00 some other text
                  -7730941132800 --> -2147483647:00:00 some other text
                   7730941132800 --> 2147483647:00:00 some other text
           1.180591620717411e+21 --> 2147483647:00:00 some other text
          -1.180591620717411e+21 --> -2147483647:00:00 some other text
          1.797693134862316e+308 --> 2147483647:00:00 some other text
         -1.797693134862316e+308 --> -2147483647:00:00 some other text
                             inf --> 2147483647:00:00 some other text
                            -inf --> -2147483647:00:00 some other text
                             nan --> --2147483648:-2147483648:       some other text
                            -nan --> --2147483648:-2147483648:       some other text
                            V E R Y   H A P P Y !
```

Comment: `time_str(buf, 59.9999996)` --> `0:60`

Comment: `time_str(buf, values less than 0 and more than -60)` --> lose the `-` sign.

Comment: @chux Thanks for your review. I have corrected the bugs.

Comment: Re: "#define MAX_INT ~(-1 << (sizeof(int) * 8 - 1)) // don't know how to do it better, any better idea ???",  Yes, use `INT_MAX` from `<limits.h>`.

Comment: To be clear: with `*printf(non_simple_format)`, code is giving up on being _fast_.

Comment: Why `& 1` in `((buf[len] != '.') & 1)`?

Comment: @CoSoCo: the use of *compound literals* as arguments for `minutes_str` is interesting. Too bad it makes the code non portable to pre-C99 compilers, such as not so old versions of MSVC.

Comment: @chux Because I'm not sure if `true` is always `1`. IIRC I've read, it could be `~0` aka `0xFF`. 
Well, but with more than one `*printf(non_simple_format)` + `atof()` in the normal program path it's not faster ... longing for my 1st answer vote on stackoverflow ;-)

Comment: @CoSoCo: `true`, as the result of boolean operations, is always `1` in C. What is confusing is that other non zero values are also true in boolean contexts. IIRC, true is all bits one in BASIC.

Comment: @CoSoCo: posting an answer to your own question is not the best way to attract votes, accepting it does not give you any reputation points :)

Comment: @CoSoCo " Because I'm not sure if true is always 1" is not relevant here.  The result of `==, !=, >, <=, ...` is _aways_ an `int 0` or `int 1`.

Comment: "This approach uses the stack instead of heap memory, so it should be faster." --> No, the usage of `sprintf()` totally swamps out any minuscule access speed advantages.

Comment: Why use `(int)(time / 60)` to do a `floor(time / 60)`?  By doing so code loses range.

Comment: "The goal is fast code, small footprint and VERY BIG values don't matter. " --> these goals are not in the question and should not be assumed - even if the poster and answerer are the same.  Requirements belong in the question.

Comment: @chqrlie Are there still any who torture themselves with M$ trojan horse? ;-)
Thinking again, it seems I could use `sprintf` (without `n`) as with `int` range I never would exceed `len = 32` and I don't know which condition could return `-1` (except `fprintf()`), so the `assert()` seems superfluous too. Any thoughts? In my project also times more than some hours never occur, so the check for `INT_MAX`is superfluous too here at me.

Comment: @chqrlie With the inspiration from the first comments I got an idea a code, fulfilling my needs. Posting this as a "comment" doesn't fit, as the code block syntax doesn't work there. So what to do with code, which has the potential?  to solve the problem. Thanks for the point :-)

Comment: @CoSoCo: avoid `sprintf`, there is no advantage over `snprintf` and it is always risky to assume buffers are large enough for the format string. `buf[len - 9] > '5'` also contains a strong assumption about `len` which will fail if `time` is a NaN. Furthermore, it is much safer to use constant format strings in `snprintf` to let the compiler verify the argument list consistency. Your approach with a variable format string prevents this.

Comment: @chux " the usage of sprintf() totally swamps out any minuscule access speed advantages". I agree, but a many mickle makes a muckle and often usage of `malloc()` also fragments the heap.. I use `(int)(time / 60)` as 1) I don't need the range of billions of hours, and 2) I assume, that the computation of format `%d` is faster as of `%f`. IMHO "fast code and small footprint" is always to be strived without notice, but opinions differ.

Comment: @chqrlie "there is no advantage over snprintf" Hm, doesn't the perpetual check of  the buffer range cost some extra cycles? "which will fail if time is a NaN" Good point, I wasn't aware of. I didn't use constant format strings, because I assume an additional `%`-parameter, just for the sign, would eat additional CPU runtime cycles. But I could use `const char * format` to help the compiler. (I actually got a warning on that, which was gone with `const`).

Comment: @chqrlie Ok, you convinced me twice, thanx. A question aside ... I added `if (time == (double)NAN)
        printf("Invalid number\n");` to my code just for testing. I'm wondering why why I never see "Invalid Number" in the output. Any idea?

Comment: @CoSoCo: `if (time == (double)NAN) ` always fails because `NAN` compares different from any number, including itself. You should use `isnan(time)` or `isfinite(time)` which will exclude infinities and NaNs. Avoid `time != time`, which would work too to detects NaNs, but is less readable, will generate more code and might also trigger a compilation warning.

Answer (score 5):

For positive time values, try this format:

```c
printf("%d:%d%g\n",
       (int)time / 60,              // number of minutes
       (int)time % 60 / 10,         // number of tens of seconds
       time - (int)time / 10 * 10); // number of seconds units and fraction thereof
```

Note however that this does not work if the fractional value is greater or equal to `0.9999995` because the last item will be rounded up to the next integer.

It would be safer to convert the time to an integer number of microseconds and print it this way:

```c
int us = (int)(time * 1000000 + 0.5);
printf("%d:%02d.%06d\n", us / 60000000, us / 1000000 % 60, us % 1000000);
```

Stripping the trailing zeroes is more tedious with this approach, I'm afraid it would be better to use a function. It is tricky to handle corner cases such as infinite values and nans correctly and keep correct rounding.

Here is an example with a test program:

```c
#include <limits.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// print a time in minutes and seconds with up to <places> decimal places and correct rounding
char *format_time(char *dest, size_t size, double time, int places) {
    char buf[400];
    int len = snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%.*f", places, time);
    int sign = (*buf == '-');
    char *p = strchr(buf, '.');
    if (p != NULL) {
        *p = '\0';
        double rounded_time = atof(buf + sign);
        double seconds = fmod(rounded_time, 60);
        double minutes = (rounded_time - seconds) / 60;
        *p = '.';
        len -= (p - buf);
        while (p[len - 1] == '0')
            len--;
        if (len == 1)
            len--;
        snprintf(dest, size, "%.*s%.0f:%02.0f%.*s",
                 sign, buf, minutes, seconds, len, p);
    } else {
        snprintf(dest, size, "%s", buf);
    }
    return dest;
}

#ifndef DBL_MAX
#define DBL_MAX  1.7976931348623157e+308
#endif

int main() {
    double a[] = {
        0, 1, 59, 60, 61,
        121.1, 121.11, 121.111, 121.1111, 121.11111, 121.111111,
        4321.0, 12345.6, 123.456789,
        129.9999994, 129.9999995,
        599.9999994, 599.9999995, 599.99999951, 599.9999999,
        23.9999999999, 59.9999994, 59.9999996,
        999.0000005, 1000.0000005, 999.9999999,
        1e6, 1e10, 1e12, 1e15, 1e18, 1e20, 1e25, 1e30,
        INT_MAX * 60.0, INT_MAX * 60.0 + 1234,
        (double)ULLONG_MAX * 64.0, DBL_MAX, 1.0 / 0.0, (double)NAN,
    };

    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]); i++) {
        char buf[400];
        printf("%32.16g --> %s\n", a[i], format_time(buf, sizeof buf, a[i], 6));
        printf("%32.16g --> %s\n", -a[i], format_time(buf, sizeof buf, -a[i], 6));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
                               0 --> 0:00
                              -0 --> -0:00
                               1 --> 0:01
                              -1 --> -0:01
                              59 --> 0:59
                             -59 --> -0:59
                              60 --> 1:00
                             -60 --> -1:00
                              61 --> 1:01
                             -61 --> -1:01
                           121.1 --> 2:01.1
                          -121.1 --> -2:01.1
                          121.11 --> 2:01.11
                         -121.11 --> -2:01.11
                         121.111 --> 2:01.111
                        -121.111 --> -2:01.111
                        121.1111 --> 2:01.1111
                       -121.1111 --> -2:01.1111
                       121.11111 --> 2:01.11111
                      -121.11111 --> -2:01.11111
                      121.111111 --> 2:01.111111
                     -121.111111 --> -2:01.111111
                            4321 --> 72:01
                           -4321 --> -72:01
                         12345.6 --> 205:45.6
                        -12345.6 --> -205:45.6
                      123.456789 --> 2:03.456789
                     -123.456789 --> -2:03.456789
                     129.9999994 --> 2:09.999999
                    -129.9999994 --> -2:09.999999
                     129.9999995 --> 2:10
                    -129.9999995 --> -2:10
                     599.9999994 --> 9:59.999999
                    -599.9999994 --> -9:59.999999
               599.9999994999999 --> 9:59.999999
              -599.9999994999999 --> -9:59.999999
                    599.99999951 --> 10:00
                   -599.99999951 --> -10:00
                     599.9999999 --> 10:00
                    -599.9999999 --> -10:00
                   23.9999999999 --> 0:24
                  -23.9999999999 --> -0:24
                      59.9999994 --> 0:59.999999
                     -59.9999994 --> -0:59.999999
                      59.9999996 --> 1:00
                     -59.9999996 --> -1:00
               999.0000005000001 --> 16:39.000001
              -999.0000005000001 --> -16:39.000001
                    1000.0000005 --> 16:40.000001
                   -1000.0000005 --> -16:40.000001
                     999.9999999 --> 16:40
                    -999.9999999 --> -16:40
                         1000000 --> 16666:40
                        -1000000 --> -16666:40
                     10000000000 --> 166666666:40
                    -10000000000 --> -166666666:40
                   1000000000000 --> 16666666666:40
                  -1000000000000 --> -16666666666:40
                1000000000000000 --> 16666666666666:40
               -1000000000000000 --> -16666666666666:40
                           1e+18 --> 16666666666666666:40
                          -1e+18 --> -16666666666666666:40
                           1e+20 --> 1666666666666666752:40
                          -1e+20 --> -1666666666666666752:40
                           1e+25 --> 166666666666666697424896:04
                          -1e+25 --> -166666666666666697424896:04
                           1e+30 --> 16666666666666666704873979904:16
                          -1e+30 --> -16666666666666666704873979904:16
                    128849018820 --> 2147483647:00
                   -128849018820 --> -2147483647:00
                    128849020054 --> 2147483667:34
                   -128849020054 --> -2147483667:34
           1.180591620717411e+21 --> 19676527011956854784:04
          -1.180591620717411e+21 --> -19676527011956854784:04
          1.797693134862316e+308 --> 2996155224770526471302168869341711813188863443303040828151933426890179148788615168103226874770040896498710950234612783266345520226229959458788332419124700807563385759480436831271585473539816641208848852443854529842024245861042631496840000693995654184204690418742185022600768539063077737531453954861570195456:08
         -1.797693134862316e+308 --> -2996155224770526471302168869341711813188863443303040828151933426890179148788615168103226874770040896498710950234612783266345520226229959458788332419124700807563385759480436831271585473539816641208848852443854529842024245861042631496840000693995654184204690418742185022600768539063077737531453954861570195456:08
                             inf --> inf
                            -inf --> -inf
                             nan --> nan
                             nan --> nan
```

Comment: Thanks for your inspiration. Yes, with your 2nd approach the stripping of the trailing zeroes is still a problem. If I could relinquish on the stripping, I just could use simple `%d:%09.6f`.

Comment: To avoid truncation of the fractional value to 5, it must be `%d:%d%.7g`.

Comment: @chux: yes, you are correct, I was being lazy. Answer updated. remaining corner cases include non finite times and huge time spans.

Comment: Note: with cases very near xxx.0000005, `lllround(time * 1000000);` will round the wrong way as `time * 1000000` imparts a rounded product  (to the ULP) before calling `llround()`.  For learner code, this degree of incorrectness is certainly tolerable.  UV

Comment: @chux: I think my new version is simpler and performs correct rounding. The behavior is different from yours on large values and `-NAN`, probably because of a different C library (Apple Libc in my case).

Comment: `print_time(59.9999994, suffix)` --> `0:60.999999` due to 2 separated roundings.

Comment: @chux: oops! due to not paying attention when switching from `strtoll` to `atof` and forgetting to clear the decimal point.

Comment: A very general solution even for BIG values, but it still lacks the possibility to nest it within further parameters in a single printf() statement!

Comment: @CoSoCo:  Some `printf` implementations can be extended with plugins, registered for currently unassigned characters, but there is no standard API for this. To achieve almost equivalent versatility, the function can be converted to format the output in an array received as an argument, along with its size, I modified the answer this way and made the number of places also an argument.

Answer (score 1):

> From a double I want to print a time in minutes and seconds including their fractional part up to 6 digits without trailing zeros.

A challenging part is the rounding that occurs when converting the `double` to text.

The following code converts the time rounded to x.dddddd seconds and then reworks the whole portion of the seconds.

Code tested for edge conditions.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int print_msf(double time_in_seconds, const char *suffix) {
  // print as seconds and a fraction - value rounded to nearest 0.000001
  //       -      308          1    . 000000  \0
  char buf[1 + (DBL_MAX_10_EXP + 1) + 1 + 6 + 1];
  sprintf(buf, "%.6f", time_in_seconds);
  int dp = '.'; // adjust for other locales if needed
  char *dpp = strchr(buf, dp);
  if (dpp == NULL) {
    return printf("%s%s\n", buf, suffix); // infinity or NaN
  } else {
    int significant_digs = 6;
    while (dpp[significant_digs] == '0') {
      significant_digs--;
    }
    dpp[1 + significant_digs] = '\0';
    *dpp = '\0';
    double t = atof(buf); // rounded whole number
    const char *sign = signbit(t) ? "-" : "";
    t = fabs(t);
    double seconds = fmod(t, 60);
    double minutes = (t - seconds) / 60;
    if (minutes) {
      seconds = fabs(seconds);
    }
    return printf("%s%.0f:%02.0f.%s%s\n", sign, minutes, seconds, dpp + 1,
        suffix);
  }
}

#include <float.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(void) {
  //double time1 = 123.456789; //   2:03.456789 some text
  //double time2 = 12345.6;    // 205:45.6 some text
  double t[] = {123.456789, 12345.6, -0.0, 59.9999994, 59.9999996,
      (double) ULLONG_MAX * 64.0, DBL_MAX, 1.0 / 0.0, NAN};
  size_t n = sizeof t / sizeof t[0];
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    printf("%30.16e --> ", t[i]);
    print_msf(t[i], " some text");
    printf("%30.16e --> ", -t[i]);
    print_msf(-t[i], " some text");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
    1.2345678900000000e+02 --> 2:03.456789 some text
   -1.2345678900000000e+02 --> -2:03.456789 some text
    1.2345600000000000e+04 --> 205:45.6 some text
   -1.2345600000000000e+04 --> -205:45.6 some text
   -0.0000000000000000e+00 --> -0:00. some text
    0.0000000000000000e+00 --> 0:00. some text
    5.9999999400000000e+01 --> 0:59.999999 some text
   -5.9999999400000000e+01 --> -0:59.999999 some text
    5.9999999600000002e+01 --> 1:00. some text
   -5.9999999600000002e+01 --> -1:00. some text
    1.1805916207174113e+21 --> 19676527011956854784:04. some text
   -1.1805916207174113e+21 --> -19676527011956854784:04. some text
   1.7976931348623157e+308 --> 2996155224770526471302168869341711813188863000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000:08. some text
  -1.7976931348623157e+308 --> -2996155224770526471302168869341711813188863000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000:08. some text
                       inf --> inf some text
                      -inf --> -inf some text
                       nan --> nan some text
                      -nan --> -nan some text
```

Comment: Nice approach, but it doesn't allow the combination with other text.

Comment: @chux: I'm afraid I don't understand how your code works: `time_in_seconds*60` is not a number of minutes, and seconds are not hundredths of minutes anyway...

Comment: @chqrlie   I too was a tad lazy - reworked and tested.